# Recursive function in promises chain

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I wanted to fire promise function several times until server will return appropriate status of request. I called this function 'checkStatus'. I don't have any idea how to achieve this.

```
saveFile() {
  this.createMetadataContainer(this.fileId).then((data) => {
    this.metadataInfo = data;
    return this.createResourceMember(data, this.fileId, this.code);
  }).then((data) => {
    this.metadataInfo = data;
    return this.applyCodeChanges(data);
  }).then((data) => {
    return this.checkStatus(data.id, this.metadataInfo);
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.deleteMetadataContainer(this.metadataInfo);
  }).then((data) => {
    this.msg = 'Code Saved';
  });

}
```

And this is how I wrote checkStatus function:

```
checkStatus(id, metadataInfo) {
  let promise = this.server.retrieve('ContainerAsyncRequest', id).then((data) => {
    if(data.State == "Completed") {
      return data;
    }else if(data.State == "Queued") {
      this.msg = 'Saving Code...';
      return setTimeout(this.checkStatus(id, metadataInfo), 2000);
    }else {
      this.msg = 'Compiler Error ' + data.CompilerErrors;
      return data;
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, and the result of the "recursive call" that you passed as a callback will be ignored. So promisify the timeout:

```
function wait(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}
```

and use that in a chain:

```
checkStatus(id, metadataInfo) {
  return this.server.retrieve('ContainerAsyncRequest', id).then(data => {
    if (data.State == "Completed") {
      return data;
    } else if (data.State == "Queued") {
      this.msg = 'Saving Code...';
      return wait(2000).then(() =>
        this.checkStatus(id, metadataInfo)
      );
    } else {
      this.msg = 'Compiler Error ' + data.CompilerErrors;
      return data;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I'm learning Promises and you help me a lot.